# Avoiding duplication on nodes with same value neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have two column in csv file, `emp_id` and `mngr_id`.  The relationship is `(emp_id)-[:WORKS_UNDER]->(mngr_id)`.  I want to merge all those nodes where emp_id=mngr_id. How to do that while creating nodes itself?

Comment: Can you precise what importer you are using? Or is it LOAD CSV from Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to ensure that you avoid creating duplicate relationships when iterating over the CSV data and avoid entering a relationship where a person works for themselves.

To avoid creating a relationship where `emp_id` and `mngr_id` identify the same person, I would suggest filtering the CSV before processing it to enter the data.  It should be much easier to omit any lines in the CSV file where the `emp_id` and `mngr_id` are the same value before passing it to Neo4j.

Next, if you're using Cypher to do the importing, something like this may be useful:

```
MERGE (emp:Person{id:'emp_id'}) MERGE (mgr:Person{id:'mngr_id'}) MERGE (emp)-[:WORKS_UNDER]->(mgr) RETURN emp,mgr
```

Note that if you run the above query multiple times in a block statement then you'll need unique identifiers for `emp` and `mgr` in each query.

Merge is explained well in the Neo4j docs: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html